# Different value of SSLprotocol (Apache)

Tags: apache, security, ssl, poodle-attack

To mitigate Poodle, we have disabled SSLv3 but some of our customers are still making outbound connections with SSLv3 and only for a certain hosts, I would like to keep SSLv3 enabled and disable it by default for others.
Can I selectively apply different SSLProtocol based on host? For example, if host is A, then SSLv3 should be enabled else only TLS1.0+. And this needs to be run-time.
We are using Apache and if I apply SSLProtocol in Location directive, it gives error that SSLprotocol can not be here

Comment: It can be different per virtual host. See the documentation. Off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I am looking at the same type of issue as it relates to old browser versions we have to support. But apparently its not possible:
*"As a rule, it is impossible to host more than one SSL virtual host on the same IP address and port."*
Taken from [here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts)

The only other way I can think of around this issue, is to create separate vhosts, where the first one to negotiate will set insecure protocols, do some detection using mod-rewrite - in my case old MS IE versions - and then specify either an "Hey your browser is old, upgrade!" page, or redirect to a more secure vhost with the correct config.

But I am still investigating and open to comments.